# Is it possible to have an inline formset built into a ModelForm or Form in django?

Tags: python, django, models, relational

Given the following example models:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    pass
class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
```

I want to define a **ReporterForm** that would allow you to add/edit articles for that reporter and also to edit the reporter's own fields. (non-existent in the example code)

I want to be able to use ReporterForm in the django admin panel so that whenever a reporter is edited, the admin can also see the articles that belong to that reporter inline.

Is there a clean way to do this? Or is this not the right model design to start with?

PS. I considered giving Reporter a ManyToManyField(Article) and just letting django do its magic but that implies that Articles can belong to many different Reporters, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what inline formsets are for. You can have inline model formsets:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

To do this in the admin site there is `InlineModelAdmin`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Article

class ReporterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ArticleInline,
    ]
```